# Extracting specific substrings (recurring elements) from a longer string in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large table of some survey answers which is saved in a peculiar format, with several **sections** each of which contains **parts**. If imported as `pandas` dataframe, sections become separate columns (from a csv file). As an example, two such columns would be:

from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

INDATA = StringIO('''Response 1,Response 2
    part 1: A; part 2: B; part 3: A; part 4: B; part 5: B,part 1: A; part 2: B; part 3: B; part 4: A
    ''')

df = pd.read_csv(INDATA, sep=',')
```

How could I end with a table like this, with individual elements:

```
| R1 | R2 | R3 | ... | R9 |
| –- | –- | –- | –-- | –- |
|  A |  B |  A | ... |  A |
```

or even like this, with list of elements:

```
| Response1       | Response2    |
| [A, B, A, B, B] | [A, B, B, A] |
```

Would `re` work, or is there something better?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `stack`, `extract`, `unstack`:

```
out = df.stack().str.extractall(':\s*(\w+);?')[0].unstack([-2, -1])
```

output:

```
      Response 1             Response 2         
match          0  1  2  3  4          0  1  2  3
0              A  B  A  B  B          A  B  B  A
```

If you also need the 'part' number:

```
out = (df
 .stack().str.extractall('part\s*(?P<part>\w+):\s*(?P<answer>\w+);?')
 .set_index('part', append=True).droplevel('match')['answer']
 .unstack([-2, -1])
)
```

output:

```
     Response 1             Response 2         
part          1  2  3  4  5          1  2  3  4
0             A  B  A  B  B          A  B  B  A
```

For a list:

```
out = (df
 .stack().str.extractall(':\s*(\w+);?')[0]
 .groupby(level=[0, 1]).agg(list).unstack()
)
```

output:

```
        Response 1    Response 2
0  [A, B, A, B, B]  [A, B, B, A]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.stack().str.split('; ').explode()
 .str.replace(r'\s*part \d+:\s+', '', regex=True).reset_index()
 .pivot_table(columns='level_1', values=0, aggfunc=list))
```

Output:

```
level_1       Response 1    Response 2
0        [A, B, A, B, B]  [A, B, B, A]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
df = pd.read_csv(INDATA, sep=",").transpose()
df[0] = df[0].str.split("; ").apply(lambda x: [e.strip().split(":")[1].strip() for e in x])
df = df.transpose()

print(df)

        Response 1    Response 2
0  [A, B, A, B, B]  [A, B, B, A]
```